# error passing a character to a function in C

Tags: c

I have the following function

```
int namecomp(char c);
```

Part of the function code

```
else if (c == 'b' || 'B')
    i=2;
```

The way I am calling it in `main()`

```
j= namecomp(s);
```

and `s` is defined as `char s = 'B';`

There is an error and whenever I am trying to use `j` the value is always `1` in the main. Please help me to know where exactly the error is. Thanks!

**EDIT**:Sorry Folks none of it worked., I am posting the complete code for help

```
int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
int i;                  
int j;
char s = 'B';
j= namecomp(s);
printf ("%d",j);
}

int namecomp(char c)
{
int i;

    if (c == 'a'||'A') 
        i=1;

    else if ((c == 'b' || c == 'B'))
    i=2;

    return i;

}
```

Comment: In the future, when you get errors during compilation or linking, always post the errors you get, as well as point out the line(s) where you get those errors.

Comment: You are fundamentally not understanding how the || operator works.

Comment: Dude, change the `|| 'A'` as well, DUH

Comment: Thanks everyone!. It worked at last., changed even the 'a' part and it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
c == 'b' || 'B'
```

always evaluates to `1`, because it's parsed as

```
(c == 'b') || 'B'
```

I'm betting you want

```
(c == 'b') || (c == 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
(c == 'b' || 'B')
```

Should be:

```
(c == 'b' || c == 'B')
```

Otherwise, you're testing this:

```
((c == 'b') || 'B')
```

Which is the same as

```
((c == 'b') || true)
```

since `'B'` is non-zero.

Remember that the logical and/or symbols can't be used *inside* a logical test, only to join logical tests together.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
(c == 'b' || 'B')    // this can be ( (c=='b') || 'B') in your compiler
```

Did you mean

```
(c == ('b' || 'B'))
```

or

```
( (c == 'b') || (c=='B') )
```

you should use the latter.

You should approach these conditions as a paranoid with paranthesis to make sure  it satisfies your conditions. Then you can try without paranthesis if it works for every condition.

Comment: @Shash you posted complete code **without taking into account any of the answers**.

Comment: @Shash the complete code you posted doesn't reflect the suggestions from the answers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I have edited the code suggested. I recompiled and reran. but still the soln is 1.

Comment: @Shash then why do you still have `c == 'a'||'A'`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes i got it at last., Thanks a lot for your persistence in this question. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`c == 'b' || 'B'` is always evaluate to 1 because `'B'` is a nonzero value, so the second operand is always true.

You need to test your condition both.

```
if (c == 'b' || c == 'B')
```